# Swiftmail imap to drafts folder

Tags: imap, swiftmailer

Is there a way to have swift mail place a message in the draft folder rather than just send. Trouble seems to be using the smtp instance with gmail. I've tried the imap_append like so:

```
$authhost="{smtp.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX.Drafts"; 

$user="asdf@asdfasd.com"; 
$pass="asdkjasdf"; 

$mbox=imap_open( $authhost, $user, $pass);

//after creating the message $msg then using imap_append

imap_append($mbox,$authhost,$msg, "\\Draft");
```

the problem though is no matter how I modify $authhost I get a couldn't open stream. Am I missing something or is there perhaps a better alternative? Thanks

Comment: You also need to use imap.gmail.com. SMTP is for sending email, imap is for accessing the mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong folder name. The name isn't INBOX.Drafts in Gmail, it's [Gmail]/Drafts. INBOX.Drafts is what e.g. Fastmail calls the mailbox.